# Delta lake in databricks - creating a table for existing storage

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I currently have an append table in databricks (spark 3, databricks 7.5)

```
parsedDf \
        .select("somefield", "anotherField",'partition', 'offset') \
        .write \
        .format("delta") \
        .mode("append") \
        .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
        .save(f"/mnt/defaultDatalake/{append_table_name}")
```

It was created with a [create table command](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#create-a-table) before and I don't use `INSERT` commands to write to it (as seen above)

Now I want to be able to use SQL logic to query it without everytime going through createOrReplaceTempView every time.  Is is possible to add a table to the current data without removing it? what changes do I need to support this?

## UPDATE:

I've tried:

```py
res= spark.sql(f"CREATE TABLE exploration.oplog USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/defaultDataLake/{append_table_name}'")
```

But get an AnalysisException

> You are trying to create an external table `exploration`.`dataitems_oplog`
> from `/mnt/defaultDataLake/specificpathhere` using Databricks Delta, but the schema is not specified when the
> input path is empty.

While the path isn't empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Databricks Runtime 7.0, you can create table in Hive metastore from the existing data, automatically discovering schema, partitioning, etc. (see [documentation for all details](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html#create-delta-table)).  The base syntax is following (replace values in `<>` with actual values):

```sql
CREATE TABLE <database>.<table>
  USING DELTA
  LOCATION '/mnt/defaultDatalake/<append_table_name>'
```

P.S. there is [more documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/tables.html#managed-and-unmanaged-tables) on different aspects of the managed vs unmanaged tables that could be useful to read.

P.P.S. Works just fine for me on DBR 7.5ML:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it, and it failed, you can see the result in the update section above

Comment: works just fine for me, on DBR 7.5ML... I would check that your folder contains `_delta` directory, etc.